# MATLAB: The determinant of a covariance matrix is either 0 or inf

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, statistics, linear-algebra

I have a 1500x1500 covariance matrix of which I am trying to calculate the determinant for EM-ML method. The covariance matrix is obtained by finding the SIGMA matrix and then passing it into the nearestSPD library [(Link)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42885-nearestspd) to make the matrix positive definite . In this case the matrix is always singular. Another method I tried was of manually generating a positive definite matrix using A'*A technique. (A was taken as a 1600x1500 matrix). This always gives me the determinant as infinite. Any idea on how I can get a positive definite matrix with a finite determinant?

Comment: The easiest way is unity matrix `eye(N)`. Claims *Determinant of any major submatrix of matrix M (and M can be understood as biggest submatrix of M) is nonzero and positive.* and *M is positive definite* are equivalent. Therefore I suppose you have problem with overflowing the `realmax` value. Have you tried to calculate `det(A*10^-6)` for example?

Comment: You can also try to find largest sumbatrix that can be evaluated by looping over `ii` the command `DetMinorA(ii)=det(A(1:ii,1:ii));`

Comment: So I tried  `det(A*10e-6)` and this is now giving me the determinant as zero. Also,   `DetMinorA(ii)=det(A(1:ii,1:ii));` gives me finite values until 145th index. What to do with this?

Comment: Then you definitely overfloat the value of `realmax`. Maybe you can try looping `DetMinor(ii,jj)=det(A(1:ii,1:ii)*10^-jj);`. Maybe the `jj=0:0.5:6` will lead to good results but interpretation will be hard. Or you can try to look for matrces with *smart* distribution of zeros.

Comment: The determinant is more than likely finite but not in 64-bit precision arithmetic.  Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, an infinite result merely means that no true zeros exists in that set (at least to the working precision of the LU decomposition Matlab uses) and without a true zero eigenvalue, the determinant is likely to overflow or underflow unless the magnitudes of the eigenvalues are chosen such that the product remains between `realmin` and `realmax`. That said, why does an infinite determinant bother affect your work?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the Multi-Variate Gaussian Distribution for an input vector x. This has the `det(SIGMA)` in the denominator that forces the function to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the determinant, or the log of the determinant? 
For example if you are computing a log likelihood of gaussians then what enters into the log likelihood is the log of the determinant. In high dimensions determinants mey not fit in a double, but its log most likely will.

If you perform a cholesky factorisation of the covariance C, with (lower triangular) factor L say so that

```
C = L*L'
```

then

```
det C = det(L) * det( L') = det(L) * det(L)
```

But the determinant of a lower triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal elements, so, taking logs above we get:

```
log det C = 2*Sum{ i | log( L[i,i])}
```

(In response to a comment)
Even if you need to calculate a gaussian pdf, it is better to calculate the log of that and exponentiate only when you need to. For example a d dimenions gaussian with covariance C (which has a cholesky factor L) and mean 0 (purely to save typing) is:

```
p(x) = exp( -0.5*x'*inv(C)*x) /( sqrt( pow(2pi,d) * det(C))
```

so

```
log p(x) = -0.5*x'*inv(C)*x - 0.5*d*log(2pi) - 0.5*log(det(C))
```

which can also be written

```
log p(x) = -0.5*y'*y - 0.5*d*log(2pi) - log(det(L))
```

where

```
y = inv(L)*x
```

Comment: Yes,  I would need the determinant as I need to generate the Gaussian Probablity Distribution Function which has a `|SIGMA|` in its denominator.